window.open does not open in a popup
In my application, I use window.open(url, 'newTarget', 'popup=1,width=500,height=500') in Google Chrome (Version 130.0.6723.92 (Official Build) (arm64)) but it opens in new tab instead of in a popup.
I can't find where is the problem on my computer
Maybe it's a problem with my professional MAC (not very familiar with apple stuff) ?
Do you have any clue ?
Thanks
